# Proving that the sequence $F_{n}(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$ is boundedly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sequences-and-series

Here is an exercise, on analysis which i am stuck.

- How do I prove that if $F_{n}(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$, then the sequence $\{F_{n}(x)\}$ is boundedly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

First, let's note that for $x\in(0,2\pi)$
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin kx}{k}=\int_{0}^{x}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\cos kt\ dt=
-\frac{x}{2}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin \frac{(2n+1)t}{2}}{2\sin{\frac{t}{2}}}\ dt$$
$$=-\frac{x}{2}+\int_{0}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{2\sin{\frac{t}{2}}}-\frac{1}{t}\right)\sin \frac{(2n+1)t}{2}\ dt +\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin \frac{(2n+1)t}{2}}{t}dt.$$
Now, the first integral at the right-hand side tends to zero by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.
The second one is equal to (via a substitution $s=(2n+1)t/2$) the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{(2n+1)x}{2}}\frac{\sin s}{s}\ ds\to\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin s}{s}\ ds=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Therefore
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin kx}{k}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}=f(x),\qquad x\in(0,2\pi).$$
The series converges on $\mathbb R$ to the periodic extension of $f(x)$.

Comment: if you take $x=0$ then the left side is a summation of zeros and the right isn't zero.

Comment: The argument works for $x\neq 2\pi m$.

Comment: @Prometheus: At that point the series converges to $(\lim_{x\to0,x>0}f(x)+\lim_{x\to0,x<0}f(x))/2=$ $(\lim_{x\to0,x>0}f(x)+\lim_{x\to2\pi,x<2\pi}f(x))/2 =$ $(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi-2\pi}{2})/2=0$.

Comment: @Prometheus Read about Dirichlet's theorems on Fourier series.

Comment: @AndreyRekalo can you explain more why that the first integral at the right-hand side tends to zero by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma ? I read the article at wiki but i faild to connect between the integral and law of Riemann–Lebesgue lemma

Comment: You went a little above and beyond

Answer (score 2):

For any $n\geq 1$, we know where the stationary points of $F_n(x)$ occur since $F_n'(x)$ has a simple closed form.
It follows that
$$ \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |F_n(x)| = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2n+1}\right) $$
and over $[0,\pi]$ we have $\sin(x)\leq \frac{4}{\pi^2}x(\pi-x)$ by concavity, therefore
$$ \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |F_n(x)| \leq \frac{8n^2}{(2n+1)^2} <2.$$
We may also prove that the sequence
$$ A_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2n+1}\right) $$
is increasing and convergent to
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \text{Si}(\pi) \approx 1.85194. $$ 
Ultimately we may check that $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}$ is the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave, i.e. the $2\pi$-periodic extension of $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ defined over $(0,2\pi)$. This is enough to ensure convergence in $L^2$, plus we have a uniform bound for $|F_n(x)|$.

Comment: Your $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |F_n(x)| = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2n+1}\right)$$ seems not ture: for $n=1$, $F_1(x)=\sin x$, the left is $1$,but the right is $\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}<1$. The right hand side maybe $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right).$$