# Is the $\sum\sin(n)/n$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving that the sequence $F_{n}(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$ is boundedly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is)

So, in my calculus class (one I'm teaching, not taking), the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ has come up a few times.  Unfortunately, as someone not exactly an expert in the convergence of sums, it seems to resist the few techniques I know.  Certain none of the usual first year calculus tricks (integral test, alternating series test, ratio test, etc.) work, and the only more tricky technique, partial summation, I can think of doesn't seem to work either (one would need that $\sum_{n=1}^N\sin(n)$ is bounded, which I believe is false).

It seems like it should converge, since it switches sign quite often, but on the other hand, the harmonic series can mess with your intuition, so I don't have much trust in that.  So, I ask to you:

> Does this series converge?

Comment: Andrey Rekalo's [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is) seems to answer your question.

Comment: According to Wolphram Alpha it converges to $\frac{1}{2}(\pi-1)$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+1+to+infinity+sin%28n%29%2Fn

Comment: @Américo: in the thread I linked to there is a derivation of that limit.

Comment: @Theo: I started writing my comment before yours was visible. Now it is irrelevant.

Comment: Given the way the question is titled, I would answer "yes"

Comment: @RossMillikan: Not necessarily, the statement may be undecidable ( not likely in this case, but, in theory, possible).

Answer (score 25):

The sum of $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sin(n) = \frac{\sin(N) - \cot \left( \frac1{2} \right) \cos \left( N \right) + \cot \left( \frac1{2} \right)}{2}$$ which is clearly bounded and hence by generalized alternating series test (also known as [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)) the sum converges.

**EDIT**
$$S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sin(n)$$

$$2\sin \left( \frac1{2} \right) \times S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left( \cos \left( n- \frac1{2}\right) - \cos \left( n+ \frac1{2}\right)\right) = \cos \left( \frac1{2} \right) - \cos \left( N + \frac1{2} \right)$$

Hence, $$S_N = \frac{\cos \left( \frac1{2} \right) - \cos \left( N + \frac1{2} \right)}{2\sin \left(\frac1{2}\right)}$$

Comment: What does the Generalized Alternating Series Test say?

Comment: @GleasSpty: The generalized alternating test is also known as Dirichlet's test. Wiki explains this in some detail http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_test

Comment: How does one prove that formula for the sum? I'm guessing that writing $sin(n) = (e^{in} - e^{-in})/(2i)$ and then following your nose gives the result, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @Michael: An elegant way in my opinion would be to multiply the sum by $\sin( \frac1{2})$ and then write it as a telescopic difference of cosines canceling out the terms to get the answer in the final form.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: $S_N$ doesn't need to have a limit. All we need is $S_N$ to be bounded. (In fact consider the alternating series $1- \frac1{2} + \frac1{3} - \frac1{4} \ldots$. The sequence of partial sums of the numerator is $1,0,1,0,\ldots$ which doesn't have a limit but it is bounded and hence the series converges.)