# Show that $\sum\limits_{ n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}}\frac{e^{2 \pi i x n}}{n}$ is a convergent series where $x$ is any real

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $\displaystyle \sum_{ n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}}^{} \frac{e^{2 \pi i xn}}{n}$ is a convergent series for all real x. I think that this could be done by breaking up the sum into two pieces; the piece that has n going to $\infty$ and the other going to $-\infty$. From there I have applied that fact that $e^{2 \pi x i n}= \cos(2\pi x n)+ i\sin(2 \pi x n)$ and then the fact that  $\displaystyle \frac{\cos(2\pi x n)}{n}+ i\frac{\sin(2 \pi x n)}{n}$ is a sequence such that the series of $\displaystyle \frac{\cos(2\pi x n)}{n}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(2 \pi x n)}{n}$ both have convergent series. The thing is that I only know these two series are convergent when n goes from 1 to infinity. Is it still true in going from -1 to - infinity? Does the method of this proof even work? Thanks!

Comment: I edited some of the TeX. Please check if everything is correct.

Comment: $\cos(2\pi n)$ is just $1$.  $\sin(2\pi n)$ is just $0$.  What am I missing?

Comment: yea for the negative values, you can take minus before the sum

Comment: Plus, unless someone tells you the order in which to sum the terms, this sum isn't well-defined (because it doesn't converge absolutely).

Comment: Ah!sorry I forget the "x" I'm gonna adjust the question.

Comment: I should mention that I only know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} cos(2\pi x n )/n $ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} sin(2\pi x n )/n $ converge because of wolfram alpha. I am trying to prove them myself though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Give a demonstration that $\sum\limits\_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ converges.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270057/give-a-demonstration-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sinnn-converges)

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\frac{e^{i2\pi nx}}{n}+\frac{e^{-i2\pi nx}}{-n}=2i\frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{n}$$ your series is equal to 
$$2i\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{n}=4\pi i\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{2n\pi}.$$
But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{2n\pi}$ is the Fourier sine series of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right), 0\le x\le 1/2.$$ Let $F(x)$  be the odd period 1 extension of f(x). By convergence of Fourier series, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{2n\pi}$ converges to $\frac{F(x-)+F(x+)}{2}$ for all $x$.

You can also use Dirichlet Test for convergence.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Consider $\dfrac{e^{2\pi ixn}}{n}+\dfrac{e^{-2\pi ixn}}{-n}$