# Show the divergence of the series $\sum \frac{\sin^2n}{n}$ without Dirichlet's test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that the series
>   $$
> \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{\sin^2n}{n}
> $$
>   is divergent.

I know how to do this with the Dirichlet's test. But is there any other way to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: You could observe $\sum \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n} = \sum \frac{1}{2n} - \sum \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n}$ and then apply to  $\sum \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n}$ a similar argument as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is?

Comment: @gimusi It involves Fourier series? However, I'm newbie on that... But, anyway, that's an interesting post and I will read carefully later.

Comment: @gimusi Actually I know how to reduce power of sin, just look for another way to prove convergence of sin(nx) for x!=2kpi

Comment: I haven't found others references here whitout Dirichlet's test. Here the  Abel partial summation has been used but it seems a generalization of Dirichlet https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270057/give-a-demonstration-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sinnn-converges?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @gimusi Well, then I shall take some time reading the post you provided.... Thanks :D

Comment: @gimusi It's the contrary, a specialization, while using Abel partial summation to prove Dirichlet's test is the more general case. Of course, one could do that, but it's a waste of time and space without any new insight.

Comment: @Macrophage Ok Let me know what you'll obtain!

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks, indeed I only gave a quick sight to the post. What is the best way without Dirichlet to prove the convergence of the remainder term $\sum \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n}$?

Comment: @gimusi I wouldn't use anything except Abel partial summation, it does the job just nicely. You could use general results about the remainder of a Fourier series, but that wouldn't be simpler, and guess which mathematician obtained those results...

Comment: The mean value of $\sin^2(n)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, hence the given series is divergent by [Kronecker's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma).

Comment: @ProfessorVector I've tried to give an answer by your suggestion, can it work? Thanks

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Hence there is a shorcut! I'll take a look to it, thanks!

Comment: It's not a coincidence that the proof of Kronecker's Lemma uses Abel partial summation.

Comment: Of any three consecutive values of $\sin^2 n$, at least one is $\geqslant \frac{1}{4}$. Hence $$\sum_{n = 1}^{3k} \frac{\sin^2 n}{n} \geqslant \sum_{m = 1}^k \frac{1}{4\cdot 3k} > \frac{1}{12}\log k\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer This morning I've read about this result in some other answer to related OP, but I can't find out it now. I can't see it is true immediately, how can we prove it? Thanks.

Comment: @gimusi If $\lvert \sin n\rvert < \frac{1}{2}$, then there is a $k$ with $\bigl(k - \frac{1}{6}\bigr)\pi < n < \bigl(k + \frac{1}{6}\bigr)\pi$. Then $\bigl(k+\frac{1}{6}\bigr)\pi < \bigl(k - \frac{1}{6}\bigr)\pi + 2 < n+2 < \bigl(k+\frac{1}{6}\bigr)\pi + 2 < \bigl(k + \frac{5}{6}\bigr)\pi$, whence $\lvert \sin (n+2)\rvert \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, very nice trick!

Comment: On a general note: The answer to the question "But is there any other way to prove it?" Is *always* "yes", regardless of what "it" is (provided there is indeed some way to prove it). This is particularly true when the given way of proving is by some special test, as here. After all, these tests were themselves proved from the definitions.

Comment: @Macrophage Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n}$$

which diverges since

$\sum \frac{1}{2n}$ diverges

$\sum \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n}$ converges

indeed by [Abel transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Method) and [Lagrange's trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange's_trigonometric_identities), let

$$a_n=\frac{1}{2n} \quad b_n=\cos(2n)=B_{n}-B_{n-1}\quad B_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos (2k)= -\frac12+\frac{\sin(2n+1)}{2\sin 1}$$

$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_nb_n=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n}
=\frac{1}{2N}\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sin(2N+1)}{2\sin 1}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left[ \left(-\frac12+\frac{\sin(2n+1)}{2\sin 1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)\right]=$$

$$=\frac{1}{2N}\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sin(2N+1)}{2\sin 1}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{4n(n+1)}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{\sin (2n+1)}{4n(n+1)\sin 1}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2n+1)}{4n(n+1)\sin 1}$$

converges absolutely by comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: It is still wrong: the Abel transformation means that you have differences multiplied by partial sums of $\cos2n$. Those are still bounded, that's why Dirichlet's test works, but you have to show that.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Seems tricky... I shall wait for some more edits to this answer.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks, I'll take a look accordingly to your suggestion!

Comment: @ProfessorVector I've revised the solution, does it work now? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's ok, now.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks a lot for the guide and patience. It's a pleasure for me can learn all this things by persons skilled and expert like you.

Comment: Minor quibble: Yours sums should start at $n=1$, not $n=0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes of course! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have

$$\begin{align}\sin^2(a)  + \sin^2(b) 
&= \frac{1-\cos(2a)}{2} + \frac{1-\cos(2b)}{2}
&= 1 - \frac12(\cos(2a)+\cos(2b))\\ = 1 - \cos(a+b)\cos(a-b)
\end{align}
$$
For any integer $k$, this leads to

$$\sin^2(2k-1) + \sin^2(2k) = 1 - \cos(4k-1)\cos(1) \ge 1-\cos(1) > 0$$

As a result, we can bound the partial sums of even number of terms from below as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2p}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}
= \sum_{k=1}^{p}\left(\frac{\sin^2(2k-1)}{2k-1} + \frac{\sin^2(2k)}{2k}\right)
\ge \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{1 - \cos(1)}{2k} = \frac{1-\cos(1)}{2}H_p$$

Since the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_p$ diverges like $\log(p)$ for large $p$, the partial sums of even number of terms diverges to $\infty$. As a consequence, the
sum $\displaystyle\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Very nice proof!

Answer (score 2):

If you march around the unit circle in strides of radian $1$, you find that $|\sin n|\gt\sqrt3/2$ at least once for every six steps.  Thus

$$\sum{\sin^2n\over n}\gt\sum{3\over4(6k)}=\sum{1\over8k}=\infty$$

(Ah, I see that Daniel Fischer gave essentially the same answer as a comment.)

Comment: This morning I've read about this result in some other answer to related OP, but I can't find out it now. I can't see it is true immediately, how can we prove it? Thanks.