# Why $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sin[n]}{n}=\frac{1}{2}(\pi-1)$?

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving that the sequence $F_{n}(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$ is boundedly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is)

From Stewart, we cannot find a calculus 2 easy way to prove this:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sin[n]}{n}=\frac{1}{2}(\pi-1)$$

Comment: What's $[n]$ suppose to be? perhaps the question has a typo?

Comment: Kerry just means $\sin(n)$

Comment: @BabakSorouh: But floor of a natural would be quite redundant.

Comment: Yeah floor or $n$ is just $n$, but this may just be it because sum of $\sin(n)/n$ is $1/2(\pi-1)$

Comment: Also look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161960/sum-inequality-sum-k-1n-frac-sin-kk-le-pi-1/183471#183471

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I need a proof acceptable at calculus 2 student's level.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{\sin{n\theta}}{n}$ is the Fourier series for  $f(\theta)=\dfrac{\pi-\theta}{2}, \;\; 0<\theta<2\pi,$ and converges uniformly on every closed interval $[\alpha, \beta], \;\; 0<\alpha<\beta<2\pi$ by Dirichlet's test.