# Evaluate $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \ n}{ n } $ using the fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I am a beginner with Fourier series and I have to evaluate the sum

$$\sum_{n  =1}^{\infty}{\sin\left(n\right) \over n}$$

I don't know which function I have to take to evaluate the fourier series ...
Someone can give me a hint ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does $\sum\dfrac{\sin n}{n}$ converge?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342637/does-sum-dfrac-sin-nn-converge)

Comment: @yoknapatawpha: I don't see Fourier series in the answers.

Comment: @BeniBogosel I grabbed the wrong link. It was supposed to be this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is. Setting $x = 1$ gives the answer to this question.

Comment: There is something similar to your question over here   --->     http://math.stackexchange.com/a/582932/85343

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large{1 \over 2}\,\left(\pi - 1\right)}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{n} \over n} = \half\pars{\,\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{n} \over n} - 1}.\quad}$  See $\large\tt details$ 
[over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/582932/85343) .

> \begin{align}
> \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{n} \over n}&=
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin{x} \over x}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\expo{2n\pi x\ic}
> \,\dd x
> =
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic kx}\,\dd k
> \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-2n\pi x\ic}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> \pi\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-1}^{1}\dd k
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic\pars{k - 2n\pi}x}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi}
> =
> \pi\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-1}^{1}\delta\pars{k - 2n\pi}\,\dd k
> \\[3mm]&=
> \pi\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{{1 \over 2\pi} - \verts{n}}
> = \pi\,\Theta\pars{1 \over 2\pi} = \pi
> \end{align}

Then,
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{n} \over n} = \half\pars{\pi - 1}}
$$

Comment: For this you have to believe the computations with divergent series that physicists use.

Comment: @GEdgar  You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What is the function that has its fourier coefficients $A_n=0$ and $B_n = \frac{1}{n}$, i.e
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sin(n x)$$

Once you have figured out $f(x)$, find $f(1)$.

By the way $f(x)$ is a "standard" function in engineering analysis.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, note that $\frac{\sin n}{n}$ is exactly the n-th Fourier coefficient of the function 
$
 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\chi_{[-1,1]}(x).
$
Since $\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)$ has a compact support, one can use the Poisson formula: 
$$
    \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \widehat{\chi_{[-1,1]}}(n) = \sqrt{2\pi} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \chi_{[-1,1]}(2\pi n) = \sqrt{2\pi},
$$
and get
$$
   \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{\sin n}{n} = \pi.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (n)}{n}= \text{Im }\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in}}{n}=\text{Im } \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \mathrm{d} x \bigg|_{x=e^i}=\text{Im } \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{1-x} \bigg|_{x=e^i}=\text{Im Log }(1-e^i) $$