# Is $\sum_{n\ge 1} \sin(n^2)/n$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Is the series
>   $$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\sin(n^2)}{n}$$
>   convergent?

My thoughts so far:

1) This is an alternating series so the integration test does not work here.

2) The Weyl inequality roughly says $$\sum_{n\le N} \sin(n^2)$$ is $O(N^{1/2+\epsilon})$, so the Dirichlet test does not work directly, but one can take $$a_n=n^{-1},b_n=\sum_{k\le n} \sin(k^2)$$
and follow the idea of Dirichlet test. The problem now is that the Weyl bound does not hold for all $N$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342637/does-sum-dfrac-sin-nn-converge.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? To get you started, notice that the sum of $(-1)^n/n$ converges while the sum of $1/n$ diverges. This sum is between them, so there is some question about how $\sin(n^2)$ behaves. If the result is true, then Dirichlet's test can probably prove it.

Comment: @Chou Thank you. I think sin(x^2) and sin(x) behave much differently.

Comment: Is there any known result, apart from Weyl's, about the estimates for the partial sums $\sum_{1}^{m}\sin n^{2}$? I would say you may instead make your question as seeking after the estimates for the sequence of the partial sums.

Comment: @Chou Good point. That is kind of what I am asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track. The key is to consider partial sums:
$$ S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n} $$
then find a good rational approximation of $\pi$ depending on $N$, apply Weyl bound (or Weyl differencing technique) to estimate $\sum_{n=1}^{k}e^{in^2}$ and finish through partial summation.

Details on page $11$ [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Svx8EY3ohUi_HKXRtKMaRgFHu9HX72bM) (it is in Italian, hope you don't mind).

Comment: Hi, Can you give the document of this link, the link is not available.

Comment: @SansiWu: link updated.