# Does $\sum{\frac{\sin (n+1/n)}{ \ln n}} \sim \sum{\frac{\sin n}{\ln n}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As was mentioned in the title, can we say that both the series
$$
\sum{\frac{\sin (n+1/n)}{\ln n}} \quad \text{ and } \quad \sum{\frac{\sin n}{\ln n}}
$$
converges or diverges simultaneously? I mean, it looks very intuitive since
$$
\sin(n+1/n) \approx \sin(n)
$$
for sufficiently large $n$. But I didn't find any rigorous Test or Rule to show that.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that $\sin(n+1/n) \approx \sin(n)$ for sufficiently large $n.$ Are you sure this is true? If so, where is a proof? I have not found one.

Comment: For the last one see the proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342637/does-sum-frac-sin-nn-converge?noredirect=1&lq=1 on davidlouwrydouda's solution. You can use the same Dirichlet criterion to show it converges.

Comment: @AdamRubinson $$\begin{align*}
\sin\!\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right) &= \sin n \cos \frac{1}{n} + \cos n \sin \frac{1}{n} \\
&= \sin n\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)
+ \cos n\left(\frac{1}{n} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right) \\&= \sin n + O(1/n)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @VladMatei But the question is not to decide whether the second converges; it is whether one can argue that both have same nature.

Comment: @ClementC. yeah, that's all correct.

Comment: Well with the asymptotic expansions you wrote the proof is done by the same dirichlet criterion. You can just bound the tails

Comment: @VladMatei See my answer. There is some work to be done :)

Comment: They both converge in short and you have essentially proved that below.

Comment: @VladMatei They both converge, but proving that they have the same nature involves handling $\sum_n \frac{\cos n}{n\ln n}$ (which is basically as hard as proving convergence of $\sum_n \frac{\sin n}{\ln n}$). So it doesn't feel like proving "they both have same nature" is any simpler than proving "they both are convergent."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b$, by a Taylor expansion around $0$ we get
$$\begin{align*}
\sin\!\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right) &= \sin n \cos \frac{1}{n} + \cos n \sin \frac{1}{n} \\
&= \sin n\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)
+ \cos n\left(\frac{1}{n} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)
\end{align*}$$
which means that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin\!\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\ln n}
&= \frac{\sin n}{\ln n} 
+ \frac{\cos n}{n\ln n}+ o\!\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) 
\end{align*}$$
since $|\sin|,|\cos|\leq 1$. This shows that, **if** you take for granted that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\cos n}{n\ln n}
$$
converges, then indeed
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sin\!\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\ln n},\quad\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{\ln n}
$$
have same nature (since the remainder, "$\sum_n o\!\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$", is absolutely convergent by comparison). The question then becomes: can one easily show that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\cos n}{n\ln n}
$$
converges? (One way: [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).)

Comment: Great explanation, thanks for the job! Yes, the last one converges by Dirichlet's test.

Comment: Glad this was helpful! @LevonMinasian