# Convergence of trigonometric sum

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Where does the series  $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} { \frac{\sin(kx)}{k} } \space \space \space \text{for} \space x \in \mathbb{R}$$converge/ uniformly converge and how would I show this? I have tried many of the standard tests for convergence and got nowhere.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is).

Answer (score 1):

Use Dirichlet's criterion. Can you determine when $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \sin kx$ is (uniformly) bounded? Alternatively, a nice proof starts by observing $$\frac{\sin kx}k=\int_0^x \cos kt dt$$

Comment: it works, thanks! - hadn't come across this test before