# Uniform convergence of functional series $ \sum_{n=1}^{n=+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+n}\sin(\frac{n}{x}),x>0$

Tags: uniform-convergence

I can't prove or refute  uniform convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{n=+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+n}\sin(\frac{n}{x}),x>0$

I tried to use [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test), but I haven't got any idea how to prove сonvergence of $\sin(n/x) $

I tried : $\sin(1/x)+..+sin(n/x)=Im(e^{i\frac{1}{x}}+..+e^{i\frac{n}{x}})=Im(e^{i-\frac{1}{x}}\frac{e^{i\frac{n}{x}}-1}{e^{i\frac{1}{x}}-1})\leq \frac{1}{|e^{i\frac{1}{x}}-1|}$

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted? Or what is interesting about this question? Usually questions posed with the tone "do this homework problem for me" are not well-received.

Comment: @Mason I tried to  use Abel's test, but I haven't got any idea  how to prove  сonvergence of sin(n/x)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is