# Prove $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin{(2nx)}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin{(nx)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am required to prove the following equality:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin{(2nx)}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin{(nx)}$$

For every $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Well, apparently, the Fourier Series of $f(x)=x$ is the RHS of the equation, which makes the equality easy to prove. The problem is that I wasn't aware of that. This question was a part of a Fourier Series exercise on the one hand, but on the other hand, I'm not sure whether am I required to know Fourier Series of some elementary functions by heart, or rather maybe there's a more sophisticated proof to the above equality.

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361589/proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-1n1-sinn-overn-1-over2

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It's more complicated here since there $n=1$, but here $n\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true, because at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the LHS is $0$, but the RHS becomes $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=2\arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @AmitZach, I believe you meant $n=1$ in place of $i=1$

Answer (score 2):

$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin(2rnx)}n$$ is the imaginary part of $$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^{i2rnx}}n=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-e^{i2rx})^n}n=\ln(1-(-e^{i2rx}))$$

Now the principal value of $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-e^{i2rx})^n}n=\ln(1+e^{i2rx})$ is $$\ln(e^{irx})+\ln(e^{irx}+e^{-irx})=\underbrace{irx}_{\text{imaginary part}}+\ln(2\cos rx)$$

Here $r=\dfrac12, r=1$

Comment: Thank you very much!